# SQL Server: minimum value in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with the following values:

```
Priority Product Supplier
-------------------------
1        ABC     JOE'S
2        ABC     MOE'S
1        DEF     JOE'S
2        DEF     MOE'S
```

The result should show the `Product+Supplier` combination with the lowest priority only.

```
1 ABC JOE'S
1 DEF JOE'S
```

Comment: This post shows zero effort or research on your part.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask  This should help you in the future.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select TOP(2) Priority, concat(Product,' ' ,Supplier)
From Table30
Order by Priority ASC
```

2)

```
SELECT  top 2 Priority,
ISNULL(Product,'') + ' ' + ISNULL(Product,'') as FullName 
FROM Table30
Order by Priority ASC
```

output

```
Priority    Product Supplier
1   ABC JOE'S
1   DEF JOE'S
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a SubQuery to get the min priority

```
Select Priority, Product, Supplier
From yourTable
Where Priority = ( Select min(Priority) From yourTable )
Order by Product, Supplier
```